# GridBagLayout strategy in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I'm struggling with putting vertical space between two components in my GridBagLayout and would like help

**(1)** successfully putting space between the first two components and

**(2)** understanding better a strategy for laying out my components based on the picture below.

Below is **(a)** what I have, **(b)** what I want, **(c)** what I've made in another tab, and **(d)** the code for the tab I'm having trouble with.

**I have this** and you can see there isn't space between the two lines.  I can't get the insets to work properly

[image]

**I want this**
[image]

**I was able to make this**, but think I did so inefficiently.
[image]

And here's the **code** for my Chinese Remainder Thm tab:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class CRTTab extends JPanel{

// for stackoverflow
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocation(200, 50);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 674));
    frame.add(new CRTTab());
    frame.pack(); //fit gui components nicely
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/** Global Variables */

//entry labels & corresponding text field
// α ≡ i (mod m)
JLabel alphaLabel1; // α ≡
JFormattedTextField iEnter; // ENTER i
JLabel leftPar1; // (mod
JFormattedTextField mEnter; // ENTER m
JLabel rightPar1; // )

// α ≡ j (mod n)
JLabel alphaLabel2; // α ≡
JFormattedTextField jEnter; // ENTER j
JLabel leftPar2; // (mod
JFormattedTextField nEnter; // ENTER n
JLabel rightPar2; // )


//Solve/Import buttons & answer label
JButton solveButton; 
JButton importButton;
JTextPane crtAnswer; // α ≡ _ (mod m*n)


//table (showing GCD computation) maintenance
JTable t;
JScrollPane scroller;


/**Construct CRT Tab
 */
CRTTab() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    // α ≡ i (mod m) in ROW 1 *****************************************************************

    //α ≡ label
    alphaLabel1 = new JLabel("α ≡", JLabel.CENTER);
    alphaLabel1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE;
    c.weightx = 0.01;
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 40 , 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(alphaLabel1, c);

    //enter i
    iEnter = new JFormattedTextField();
    iEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    alphaLabel1.setLabelFor(iEnter);

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 35.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 5 , 0, 0); //top left bottom right
    c.gridx = 1;
    add(iEnter, c);

    //(mod label
    leftPar1 = new JLabel("(mod");
    leftPar1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 0.01;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(leftPar1, c);

    //enter m
    mEnter = new JFormattedTextField();
    mEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    leftPar1.setLabelFor(mEnter);

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 35.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 10 , 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    c.gridx = 3;
    add(mEnter, c);

    //) label
    rightPar1 = new JLabel(")");
    rightPar1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 0.01;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.gridx = 4;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 40); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(rightPar1, c);


    // ROW 2 ******************************************************************************************0

    //α ≡ label
    alphaLabel2 = new JLabel("α ≡", JLabel.CENTER);
    alphaLabel2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.weighty = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BELOW_BASELINE;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 40 , 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(alphaLabel2, c);

    //enter j
    jEnter = new JFormattedTextField();
    jEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    alphaLabel2.setLabelFor(jEnter);

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 35.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(20, 5 , 0, 0); //top left bottom right
    c.gridx = 1;
    add(jEnter, c);

    //(mod label
    leftPar2 = new JLabel("(mod");
    leftPar2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 0.01;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(leftPar2, c);

    //enter m
    nEnter = new JFormattedTextField();
    nEnter.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
    leftPar2.setLabelFor(nEnter);

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 35.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(20, 10 , 0, 0); //top, left, bottom, right
    c.gridx = 3;
    add(nEnter, c);

    //) label
    rightPar2 = new JLabel(")");
    rightPar2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));

    //constraints
    c.weightx = 0.01;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.gridx = 4;
    c.insets = new Insets(0, 5, 0, 40); //top, left, bottom, right
    add(rightPar2, c);




}//end constructor

}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change the top/bottom values in the insets?

Comment: I can make the JFormattedTextField boxes that you enter numbers in take up more space than the one below/above it, but it still looks like one box split in half with no space in between.  I would like space in between

Comment: Maybe you can have a separate layout for the text fields so that they are easier to work with.

Comment: Seems like DizzyCode answer is valid, I'm having the same problem, but I'm sure there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @AntonioAguilar what worked for me was the main tab to extend JPanel with BoxLayout, then I had JPanels inside the main JPanel for each component.

* panel1() - enter 1st congruence (default layout)

* panel2() - enter 2nd congruence (default layout)

* panel3() - "Solve System" & "Show GCD" buttons (BoxLayout)

* panel4() - whitespace strip for answer (GridBagLayout)

...And so on.
See: [Picture here](https://github.com/GageHeeringa/extended-euclidean-visual/blob/master/Example%20Program.png)

Comment: @Gage, Would be nice if you could answer yourself in the Q&A StackOverflow allows, to help community and me understand better (lol).